# Why is Visual Basics Console.ReadLine Buggy and can I fix it?

Tags: vb.net, input, command-line, return, console-application

Hey question about a visual basics program, I am using Console.ReadLine into a string but it seems when I get to that part of the program or any part of my console program the keyboard enter key enters twice or something it completly skips a ReadLine and recieves the input.length 0 before I even have a chance to enter a string.

This isnt runable without my full code I dont think but I cant seem to get ReadLine to prompt for a string when it is initially run, it always returns 0 once and then loops normally. Im wondering if that has something to do with my keyboard or keyboard settings for a visual basics program or command line.

I dont think its a keyboard error because when I am entering code into visual basics it works fine and doesnt send two returns. I couldnt get the full code in code blocks.

...

```
Shared Sub Main()
    Dim s As New Space()
    Dim Ship As New Ships()
    Dim Run As Boolean = True
    Dim ChooseName As Boolean = True
    Dim ch As Char
    Dim PlayerName As String

    While Run = True
        s.PrintWelcome()
        ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read())
        If ch = "1" Then
            While ChooseName = True
                Console.WriteLine("Choose a Name Less then 50 Characters: ")
                PlayerName = Console.ReadLine()
                If PlayerName.Length > 50 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Name is to Long!")
                ElseIf PlayerName = "Q" Then
                    Run = False
                    Exit While
                ElseIf PlayerName.Length <= 0 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Player name or Q by itself to quit.")
                Else
                    ChooseName = False
                    Console.WriteLine("PlayerName: " & PlayerName & " PlayerName.Length: {0}", PlayerName.Length)
                End If
            End While
            If Run = True Then

            End If
        ElseIf ch = "2" Then
        ElseIf ch = "3" Then
            Run = False
        ElseIf ch = "Q" Then
            Run = False
        Else
            s.PrintWelcome()
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

...

Comment: Why is that method declared `Shared`? If you create a Console application then the IDE automatically generates a module and declares a `Main` method in it. The `Shared` keyword is not valid in that context so you must have changed something.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().FirstOrDefault())`

Comment: @Jimi, firstly, the `Convert.ToChar` would not be needed in that case. That said, given that `ch` is actually compared to `String` values later anyway, I would suggest that `ch` should actually be declared as type `String` and then that should just be `ch = Console.ReadLine()` or maybe  `ch = Console.ReadLine().TooUpper()`. I would also suggest that `ch` be given a decent name that describes its purpose, as pretty much all identifiers should.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, I forgot to remove the conversion when I pasted in the OP code. Of course you can change `ch` to string and just use `Console.ReadLine()`, but I don't know whether the OP needs a char or a string there. The comparison of a char with a string of length = 1 works anyway. -- I didn't notice `Shared` on `Sub Main()` :)

Comment: Console.ReadLine().FirstOrDefault() worked thanks! Is there a reason I have to do that instead of a normal ReadLine call tho?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine().FirstOrDefault()` is used to swallow the carriage return and take only the first char, so if a User inputs `1`, `11`, `123` it always counts as just `1` (and it handles a null string input). It depends of what you want to do, or what you expect there.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you really ought to be structuring your code more like this:

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Do
            Console.Write("Please select a menu item from 1, 2, 3 or Q to quit: ")

            Dim menuSelection = Console.ReadKey()
            Dim input As String = Nothing

            Console.WriteLine()

            Select Case menuSelection.KeyChar
                Case "1"c
                    Console.WriteLine("What did you want to say about 1?")
                    input = Console.ReadLine()
                Case "2"c
                    Console.WriteLine("What did you want to say about 2?")
                    input = Console.ReadLine()
                Case "3"c
                    Console.WriteLine("What did you want to say about 3?")
                    input = Console.ReadLine()
                Case "q"c, "Q"c
                    Exit Do
                Case Else
                    'Do nothing before repeating the prompt.
            End Select

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(input) Then
                Console.WriteLine("You said: " & input)
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub

End Module
```

The `ReadKey` call will immediately read the first key entered by the user. Rather than requiring the user to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after that key, the application writes the line break itself. It then tests the chararacter represented by that key to see if it is a valid menu item. If it is, it does whatever is appropriate for that item, whether that be reading a line of input or quitting. If the key does not represent a valid menu item then it simply loops back to the prompt. Note also that the `Char` value entered by the user is actually compared to `Char` literals, the way it should be done, rather than `String` literals.